# How to generate pdf from url

Tags: php, pdf

How could i generate a pdf file using url without using any api ?
Or if any free api provider then please tell me.

I have a file www.highstore.in/myticket.php
In this file php & MySQL is used to get data now i want to convert this data as it is in PDF format.

Comment: Look at the dompdf library http://dompdf.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not an API, but you can use a *FPDF* OPEN SOURCE library, it's too easy to use. you can see some examples here :

[FPDF LIBRARY](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: I want to convert a pdf from url . Not html :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of free libraries to generate pdf files

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/226/top-5-best-open-source-pdf-generation-libraries-for-php

If you want to return generated `pdf` as a result of execution of a `PHP` script you should change header content-type into

`header("Content-type:application/pdf");`